# Hide text and display icons

Tags: css

in site we have like below text as in [link1](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81//yang-yin.html) :

[image]

But instead of text - `Black & Green` , i want to display **images** as below or **css icons** as [here](http://codepen.io/shahil/pen/PWWdRY)....

[image]

i uploaded Black & Green images to below path :

http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/media/catalog/custom/green.png

http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/media/catalog/custom/black.png

i am trying below css to display icons instead of text, but its not displaying any icons in site. I want to **hide text with icons.**

```
label[for=options_455_2]
   {
      width:50px; height:50px; background:#000; border-radius:50%;

   }
```

Comment: so you are using `label`s and `input` radio buttons?

Comment: @kukkuz yes, you are right.....

Comment: Please: show the [mcve] HTML, that way you can get specific help without us having to guess at your code.

Comment: @kukkuz Thanks a lot for support.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `display:block` on label. So that empty label does not have zero width and height.

Secondly link you took the idea from is setting the `background-color`. but you are not. Either use different background-colors (like that link) or use `background-image` property.

Here's a working snippet.

```css
label{
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  border-radius:50%;
  background-image:url("http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/media/catalog/custom/green.png");
  background-size:cover;
  display:block;
  color:transparent;
}
```

```html
<label>jdjshjkdhd</label>
```

Comment: sorry, this didt worked for me..... you can check [here](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/yang-yin.html) , instead of image, it extend the background line covering text `Black`

Comment: still same result , am i missing somewhere - [link](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/yang-yin.html)

Comment: ok, I edited my answer. just add  `color:transparent;` to the labels

Comment: sorry for delay, i updated your code , now icons are displaying, but icons are  repeating multiple times as here : http://prnt.sc/dxlxy3  , [link](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/yang-yin.html) , but i want to replace those by text `black`

Comment: sorry, I didn't get that, you are showing two labels green image and black text.. after that you are showing two inputs greeen and black. Now what is repeating in this or are you talking about something after this block

Comment: first thing is `icons` are displaying multiple times, but all i wanted is i want to replace text `Black` and `green` by icons, so icon should display only one time, but its displaying 4 times

Comment: I am terribly sorry, I didn't see your comment. I have joined the chat, if you're still there.

Comment: @Pete Thanks a lot for support..... sorry as i am poor in coding, i failed to make your solution work.....

Comment: I have joined the chat.

Answer (score 0):

if you have no influence on html I can give you a hack :))

```
label {
color: #fff;
width: 0px;
}

label::before {
display: block;
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
background: green;
border-radius: 50%;

}
```

here is codepen http://codepen.io/kejt/pen/EZZGeE

Comment: as per my requirement, i used your code like this , but didt worked for me.... please check code `label[for=options_455_3]
   {
overflow: hidden;
width: 0px;
   }
   
 label[for=options_455_3] ::before {
  display: block;
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
background: green;
border-radius: 50%;
 }`

Comment: sorry for delay, i tried your code like this :  `label[for=options_455_2]  {

color: #fff;
width: 0px;

}

label[for=options_455_2] ::before {
 
display: block;
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
background: green;
border-radius: 50%;
 
}`  but it didt displayed any icons....

Comment: when you copy your code there is a whitespace between label[for=options_455_2] and ::before, is it also in your code? please, remove it

Comment: Thanks a lot for support..... sorry as i am poor in coding, i failed to make your solution work.....

Answer (score 0):

This workaround could help you with your requirements. Change the color of background based on for value.

```
label[for=options_453_2]{position:relative;border-radius:50% !important;max-width: 20px !important;}
label[for=options_453_2]:before{background: #000 !important;display:block;content: "";position: absolute;left: 0;top: 0;z-index: 9999;width: 100%;height: 100%;}
```