# Button not working after using jquery.min.js

Tags: javascript, jquery

We are using below code as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41740727/hide-text-and-display-icons/) to display icons instead of text , but after we used below code, mainly **Jquery.min.js** now "**add to cart**" button is not working in [this link](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/yang-yin.html).

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
   var inner = Array();
   inner = $(" .product-options ul.options-list .label>label");
   for (i = 0; i < inner.length; i++) {
     var classN = inner[i].innerText;
     if (classN == "Black" || classN == "Green") {
       inner.eq(i).addClass(classN);
     }
   }
 });

</script>
```

main console error :

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'submit' of undefined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick** at below line code.

```
<button type="button" title="Add to Cart" class="button btn-cart" onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit(this)"><span><span>Add to Cart</span></span></button>
```

[image]

**Edit**

When we dont load jquery, `Add to cart` button is working fine as [here](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/stunning-bike-racer-apple-iphone-7-plus-phone-case.html)

Comment: Any errors in your console?

Comment: add your markup ...if you can create a fiddle

Comment: are you looking at the console errors?

Comment: You posted some code that has nothing to do with the "add to cart" button. Anyways, you have an Cannot read property 'submit' of undefined when pressed click. Is add to cart button selector correct?

Comment: @empiric that may be firewall issue, its working.... please check updated question  for console errors

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).*

Comment: @Geeky i tried to create fidddle, but as it contains lot of php code, that didt worked, please check [link](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/yang-yin.html)

Comment: @Roljhon please check updated question, i added console errors

Comment: @FedericoAlecci once i remove `jquery version script` add to cart is working fine, so i thought `add to cart` button code not required , please loook at [link](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/yang-yin.html) once...

Comment: @user5348fh8y5 please, add the button handler code, so we can figure the problem out.

Comment: @FedericoAlecci now i updated `add to cart`  button code in question, please check it....

Comment: It's not actually the jQuery's fault, its actually your code itself. I tried to remove the jquery script from the index file. I used fiddler debugger to do this and still getting the same issue, you should isolate your errors to debug a lot faster. And even firing `productAddToCartForm` in the console will result to an undefined object https://www.screencast.com/t/JoSPsRwb6

Comment: @Roljhon when jquery is not loaded, `add to cart` is working fine in other link : http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/stunning-bike-racer-apple-iphone-7-plus-phone-case.html

Comment: I can only speak for myself, but I have the feeling others would go along with the idea. I will not click any link to an internet address with a non-default port. Also, if you would actually read the comment and link provided by @empiric, it would tell you that we expect all relevant code to be **in the question itself**, not on a third-party site.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan you are absolutely right, i  am extremely sorry for that.....

Comment: This could probably be a conflict betwen using jQuery and prototype at the same time

Comment: @Roljhon Thanks, is there any way to fix this ?

Comment: @empiric Thanks for your suggestions, from next time i will put more effort to post good question....

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Thanks for your suggestions, from next time i will put more effort to post good question....

Comment: @Geeky Thanks for your help.....

Comment: @FedericoAlecci Thanks for your help.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue buddy! :)

I found couple instances of jquery.min.js script call in your HTML, I'm not sure why are you doing this but this causes the `$.noConflict()` not to work which didn't override the normal behavior of jQuery and Prototype working on the same page.

Here is the screenshot of what I removed

[image: screenshot]

Removed all instances of the `<head>` tag except the first one and the first jquery.min.js script call from your HTML.

Goodluck!

****UPDATE****

As per as the OP's concern, this is running in magento and the code from the above image is strictly needed. So putting a `var jQuery = $.noConclict()` after the jquery.min.js script call and replacing `$` with `jQuery` in the `document.ready` function fixes the issue.

Comment: I tried it using fiddler. I bet it will work but it depends on how you'll do it.

Comment: Why embed an image? Just paste the text. Also, the prefered image host is Imgur, there is even a convenient upload button in the editor...

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl I didn't actually embed the image, I used screencast, not sure about that. sorry

Comment: sorry to inform what i understood is you told me to use `<html>` before `<head>` , other than that i cant able to see any changes compare to my original code, can you please tell me what code i need to replace ?

Comment: Just simply find `<head>` tag, this contains only the jquery.min.js script call  and a document ready. simply removed all of it. then that's it

Comment: @user5348fh8y5 see the image from my answer.